# Sleep for 1000 years

Tags: code-golf, date

Some `sleep` commands implement a delay of an integer number of seconds. However, 2³² seconds is only about 100 years. Bug! What if you need a larger delay?

Make a program or a function which waits for 1000 years, with an error of less than ±10%. Because it's too time-consuming to test, please explain how/why your solution works! (unless it's somehow obvious)

You don't need to worry about wasting CPU power - it can be a busy-loop. Assume that nothing special happens while your program waits - no hardware errors or power failures, and  the computer's clock magically continues running (even when it's on battery power).

What the solution should do after the sleep is finished:

- If it's a function: return to caller
- If it's a program: terminate (with or without error) or do something observable by user (e.g. display a message or play a sound)

Comment: “Around computers it is difficult
to find the correct unit of time to
measure progress.  Some cathedrals took a century to complete.  Can you imagine the grandeur and scope of a program that would take as long?”  —Epigrams in
Programming, ACM SIGPLAN Sept. 1982. (via `fortune` CLI app)

Comment: `Because it's too time-consuming to test,`: If your implementation is based on _polling_ a real‑time clock (RTC), you may simply _adjust_ the RTC to a date/time about 1 kiloyears in the future. In UNIX‑like environments like Linux or FreeBSD you can invoke the [`date`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_%28Unix%29) command‑line utility to that end.

`What if you need a larger delay?`: Easy, employ [time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation). 

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
35WY.
```

This waits for 34359738368 seconds, which is a little more than 1089 years and a half.

[Don't try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39g0PFLv/38A)

#### Explanation

```
35     % Push 35
W      % 2 raised to that. Gives 34359738368
Y.     % Pause for that many seconds
```

Comment: I doubt anyone will find any way that beats this. Then again, I'm surprised to see it this short, so I could be surprised again. The only way I can think of is if another language can do basically the same thing but has a 1-character sleep function (as opposed to 2 ["Y."]).

Answer (score 83):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>40 36 32 29 26</s> 24 bytes

```c
i;f(){--i&&f(sleep(7));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk1Ds1pXN1NNLU2jOCc1tUDDXFPTuvZ/bmJmHlAGKAvkAAA)

-3 thanks to @gastropner.

-1 recursive approach thanks to @AZTECCO.

4294967295*7/86400/365.25 ~ 952.69

Comment: Can bump the sleep a hair more with a more accurate year: 365.242193…

Comment: Witchcraft! Dark Arts!!! Why is it possible to call a function as it is being declared, and more precisely, how can you give a parameter to a parameterless function???

Comment: @M.Herzkamp (1) because why wouldn't you be able to? (2) in C, a function defined with an empty parameter list (as opposed to a `void` parameter list) is treated as a varargs function.

Comment: would be more interested why you think this runs 2^32 times - and not 2^31 times - as an i variable would be predefined as going from -2^31 to (2^31)-1 (signed) and I dont see an unsigned definition

Comment: @eagle275 Because i goes from 0 to -1, then all the way to -(2^31), the next decrement takes i to (2^31)-1, then i goes all the way back to 0;

Comment: Is `i` somehow guaranteed to be initialized to 0? I still operate under the assumption that it should be treated as garbage if not initialized; then again, I frequently have to work with ancient legacy code that still uses old compilers.

Comment: @Aaron [Globals in C are initialized to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015656/are-global-variables-always-initialized-to-zero-in-c)

Comment: Signed overflow is undefined, so the compiler is allowed to optimize the check out.

Comment: @ErburethsaysReinstateMonica Good thing there are no optimisation flags used  then. The default is [optimization off](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Optimization-Levels.html): "generates unoptimized code".

Comment: This answer is more appropriate on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: I hope the compiler implements proper tail call elimination. Otherwise you will run into an out of memory error, unless your computer happens to have 45*8 TB heap memory. Ok, not that difficult if you are using virtual memory and swap it all out.

Comment: I voted for this answer when it wasn't so great. Too bad I cannot vote again!

Comment: Wrong, unfortunately: this relies on something that C cannot guarantee (and in fact, guarantees to be false in many old systems and probably all future (>32bit) ones...) : that the size of int is 32bits. Read carefully the (old but GREAT) C faq : it's answer 1.1 for exemple: http://c-faq.com/decl/inttypes.html states carefully that int "... *can* hold values up to 32,767" because the only thing C says is than "int" is AT LEAST 16 bit (not 32, and can be 36, 18, and any number of bits that can hold 16 bits inside). Thus you end up sleeping very different amount of times depending on the system.

Comment: so maybe edit to change `i` to `int32_t i=0` (as not sure int32_t is set to 0 by default). Needs a c99 (or more recent) compiler, and a machine that can have int on 32 bits (this depends on the system, and the compiler will then barf out if your system doesn't support int32_t)

Comment: @OlivierDulac As long as it works for some compiler on some system, [the answer is valid](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/3808).

Answer (score 41):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) (Excluding CPython on Windows), 28 bytes

```python
import time
time.sleep(3e10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVC0ToFeekphZoGKcaGmj@/w8A) (Remember to put something in your will so future generations can check that it ended on time.)

`time.sleep(seconds)` takes either an int or a float.

`1000*365.2422*24*60*60/3e10 == 1.051897536` which is an error of less than 10%.

Comment: This does not work in CPython on Windows. [time.sleep of CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Modules/timemodule.c#L1861) only supports sleeping up to 2^32-1 ms = a little bit less than 50 days. (Limit imposed by WinAPI `Sleep`)

Comment: @JiminP Just goes to show you: If you want to run something for a millennium -  don't do it on Windows! T_T

Answer (score 30):

## bash, <strike>26</strike> 24 bytes

I think part of the challenge here is to not have a signed 32 bit overflow, so:

```
ping -i86400 -c365243 t.co
```

The idea here is to make 1000 years of pings (365243), once per day (86400).

"t.co" is simply a four character internet hostname (in this case, a link shortener).  If your local host table has a one character hostname, you can subtract 3 bytes.

Edit: [corvus-192](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/46901/corvus-192) points out that country code ai resolves as a host, so you can write:

```
ping -i86400 -c365243 ai
```

As this <strike>will</strike> should work for anyone, I will accept this.  Saved 2 bytes.

Comment: You have more faith in the longevity of IPv4 than I do.

Comment: @Caleb: This only has to *start* today, on a system that will stay up for 1000 years, not continue to do IPv4 DNS lookups.  But yes, `ping` on my GNU/Linux system supports IPv6 addresses (without having to invoke it as `ping6`), and localhost is `::1` saving 1 byte.  `ping ::` also works, for the IPv6 unspecified address, saving 2 bytes but getting error messages (`ping: sendmsg: Network is unreachable`).

Comment: Do you _need_ to ping a working domain? Wouldn't this still work according to spec if all the pings failed by calling a fake domain like `t`?

Comment: With my version of ping, `ping 1` attempts to ping 0.0.0.1, which saves 3 characters if you can get that IP to ping.

Comment: @Vortico It does not on my ubuntu 16.04 system and ping does not work on TIO so i wouldn't say this is valid.

Comment: I don't like the IPv6 addresses as it requires a particularly recent Linux and IPv6 enabled.  It wont work to simply `ping t` because the address must resolve, though it is not the case that there must be a host there.  `ping 1` should not work, and does not for me.  I also don't want to assume a shorter alias in /etc/hosts, as not everyone would have that, but as noted, it can shorten the golf.  As for the longevity of IPv4: it has already survived decades past it's replacement.  :-)

Comment: For me, `ai` resolves to 209.59.119.34, which is 2 bytes shorter.

Answer (score 23):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 10 bytes

```ruby
sleep 3e10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/vzgnNbVAwTjV0OD/fwA)

There are approximately \$3*10^{10}\$ seconds in a thousand years.

Comment: `sleep 32e9` is more accurate and has the same size in bytes

Comment: 31557600000 seconds

Comment: "Try it online!". LOL

Answer (score 21):

### 6502 Machine Code on an Apple II, <strike>10</strike> 9 bytes

Code is actually platform-independent, other than it relies on the Apple's clock speed of 1.023 MHz for timing.

Code starts at address 0x0000:

`0000: A2 CA F6 44 F0 FB D0 F8 F7`

Saved an additional byte. Details are below original answer.

#### Original answer:

Code starts at address 0x0059:

`0059: A2 08 F6 60 D0 FA CA D0 F9 F5`

Disassembly:

```
loop1: 0059- A2 nn     LDX #$nn   ; 2 cyc
loop2: 005B- F6 60     INC $60,X  ; 6 cyc
       005D- D0 FA     BNE loop1  ; 2-3 cyc
       005F- CA        DEX        ; 2 cyc
       0060- D0 F9     BNE loop2  ; 2-3 cyc
       0062- pp        DB  $pp    ; data byte
```

This is a fairly simple routine that increments a multi-byte counter. When the counter rolls over, the last branch instruction gets modified so that it points to an RTS instruction, which provides the exit for the routine.

loop1 is taken for each increment of the counter and takes 11 cycles per iteration. loop2 is taken for each byte carried over and takes 13 cycles per iteration. So if we increment the counter N times, we spend approximately:

11*N + 13*(1/256 + 1/(256^2) + 1/(256^3) + ...)*N
= 11.05*N cycles

1000 years is 365242*86400*1023000 = 32282717702400000 cycles

So we need N = 2921512914244345 +/- 10%

Or a range of 2629361622819911 - 3213664205668779
  = 0x095763F583A447 - 0x0B6ACF816801AB

In the code above, set pp = 0xF5 and nn = 0x08.

This gives us a 7-byte counter in memory locations 0x62-0x68
(with MSB at lowest address, i.e. big endian). Only location 0x62
is initialized, so our starting counter value could be anywhere
from 0xF5000000000000 to 0xF5FFFFFFFFFFFF.

We'll increment the counter until it rolls over to 0, which
will cause the byte at 0x61 to increment by 1, which happens
to be the branch target for loop2. On the first byte carry
after rollover-- when the counter hits 0x100-- we'll hit the
modified branch instruction for the first time. This will take
us to address 0x5C (loop2+1). The 0x60 byte there is the opcode
for "Return from Subroutine" (RTS) which provides our exit.

So our total loop count is between, 0x0A000000000101 and
0x0B000000000100, which is a subset of the range we calculated
which gives us the necessary number of cycles +/- 10%.

Now that we have the exact starting and ending counter values,
we could go back and calculate the exact cycle counts, but given
how much margin there is, I'm willing to hand-wave that part.

You can actually test it out with smaller values of nn. For example nn of 4 will pause for several seconds.

#### 9-byte answer:

```
0000- A2 CA     LDX #$CA   ; 2 cyc
0002- F6 44     INC $44,X  ; 6 cyc
0004- F0 FB     BEQ $0001  ; 2-3 cyc (rollover)
0006- D0 F8     BNE $0000  ; 2-3 cyc (non-rollover)
0008- F7        DB  $F7    ; data byte
```

Saved one byte by folding the DEX opcode into the
argument for LDX.

Instead of 11.05 cycles, each counter increment is now
13 + 11*(1/256 + 1/(256^2) + ...) = 13.043 cycles.

Now we need 2475073064976549 +/- 10% iterations,
or a range of 0x7E9F591BF7A2E - 0x9AC2C23EA071C.

So now we initialize the 7-byte counter to something
between 0xF7000000000000 and 0xF7FFFFFFFFFFFF. This ends
up giving between 0x08000000000001 and 0x09000000000000
loop iterations, which is within the +/-10% needed.

When the counter rolls over to 0, the last branch
gets modified to jump to $0001, which leads to an increment
of the BNE opcode itself (to a CMP instruction, which
for our purpose is effectively a no-op). Code then falls
through to $0008, which now contains a 0 (because of counter
rollover). A 0 byte is a BRK instruction, which drops you
back to the system monitor, ending the routine.

Answer (score 20):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>35</s> <s>32</s> <s>24</s> <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```powershell
1..3e4|%{sleep 1mb}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31BPzzjVpEa1ujgnNbVAwTA3qfb/fwA)

Strangely, the maximum seconds value for `Start-Sleep` is `2147483`. No, I don't know why it's such an odd value. That works out to a little over `2` megabytes (`2097152`). `1mb * 30000 / 86400 / 365.25` is `996.821051030497`, so a little under 1000 years. I could get more exact using a different value than `3e4`, but this is within the allowed margin and I'm lazy.

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to ceilingcat.*
*Saved 8 bytes thanks to Jeff Zeitlin.*
*Saved 3 bytes thanks to Neil.*
*Saved 2 bytes thanks to Mark Henderson and Nahuel Fouilleul.*

Comment: Well, `2147483` is 1/1000th of a max 32-bit integer, so perhaps Powershell internally does some unit conversions with milliseconds or something. See [here (MaxIdleTimeoutSec)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/7e423e7451a4530060422aff1c821c0dc0712372/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/remoting/commands/NewPSSessionConfigurationOptionCommand.cs)

Comment: Save 8 bytes with `1..15000|%{sleep 2.04mb}`.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Good grief, I'm missing the obvious golfs today. Thanks!

Comment: Why not `sleep 2mb`? You'll get a little under 1000 years, but other than that it should be fine, I'd have thought?

Comment: Save yourself an extra byte with `1..15e3`

Comment: or `1..3e4` and `sleep 1mb`

Answer (score 15):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
27;°.W
```

Inspired by [the other answer in 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196965/25315).

Waits for 10<sup>27/2</sup> milliseconds, or about [1002 years](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=convert+31622776601683+milliseconds+to+years).

Explanation:

```
27            push the number 27
  ;           divide by 2
   °          replace X by 10 to the power of X
    .W        wait that number of milliseconds
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fyNz60Aa98P//AQ)

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? How does that translate to 10^(27/2)?

Comment: Nice approach! I actually just found another 6-byter myself as well. :)

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
32œS$ȷ9¡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Y6OjkYJUT2y0PLfz/HwA)

A niladic link which waits for 32 seconds 1 billion times. 32,000,000,000 is within 10% of 31,557,600,000 seconds which is 1,000 years (ignoring leap seconds and ignoring the fact that centuries indivisible by 400 are not leap years).

Answer (score 11):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
Ｆ³³ＲＸφ⁴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8tv0hBw9hYUyEoNa0otThDIyC/PLVII01HwVBT0/r///@6ZTkA) Link is to verbose version of code with a speed up factor of 1e9 (obtained by changing the ⁴ into a a ¹) so that it doesn't time on TIO. Explanation:

```
Ｆ³³
```

Repeat 33 times.

```
ＲＸφ⁴
```

Refresh the screen, but delay 1000⁴ milliseconds between refreshes.

Although there are 33 refreshes, there are only 32 intervals, so the total delay is 32000000000000 milliseconds or approximately 1015 years.

Comment: I love the implications of “Try it online!” _It was the year 12019, and the ancient computer finally woke up. Amazed, the engineers used the methods of long-dead programmers to find what was running. The computer said, Charcoal. The gods had spoken, and in that moment, programming became an important force in the world once again._

Comment: @BalinKingOfMoria 1000 years after now is 3019, not 12019 ;)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton The code sleeps for almost 1015 years anyway, so it would wake up some time during 3034.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Oooops, I misremembered it as 10,000 years *facepalm*

Comment: I can't stand cryptic or archaic languages and would prefer everyone forget about them and use ones that are more readable (maybe Charcoal is and this is just an (ab)use of it?), but this still gets +1 for the effort even though it makes me cringe.

Comment: can this really be expressed in 7 bytes? Those are 7 characters but in UTF-8 they would be more bytes

Comment: @Agos Charcoal has its own code page (see the wiki in the linked github) although it will accept UTF-8 as well (there's a command-line flag for it).

Comment: clever! then the above translates to these 7 bytes: 0x46 B3 B3 B3 52 58 E6 B4

Comment: @Agos Nearly; they're actually 0xC6 B3 B3 B3 D2 D8 E6 B4.

Answer (score 10):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 23 bytes

```java
v->Thread.sleep(7L<<42)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU6xDoIwEN39ihthwMGYOIBubjphXIzDWU4o1tK0pZoYvr0WqJPD5V3evXfvtegwa6uHZwKNgSNyCZ8FAJeW9B0ZQSmIFOmJBXAdr8CMVHIeV5eCbXT3MrB/M1KWdzIPwiGM6m@CMzAWbYDJ@Azvk9JqLuvLFVDX5t8eg36xJuIWvMt2p0YTVsu5wOZQFOtV6vPJEIXxJnsh0rnJ4L8)

It's hard to find a short way to write a number in Java. `Thread.sleep` only accepts a `long` number of milliseconds. So the standard answer `3e10` doesn't work because it's a double. Casting it to a long would be the appropriate action. But it would still be 1000 too small. So enter `3e13` which is closer. But fortunately, `7L<<42` is `30,786,325,577,728`, which is close to the actual count of 1000 years, and is a `long` without cast, so 4 bytes shorter than `(long)3e13`.

### Credits

- -4 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) by replacing `(long)3e13` with `7L<<42`.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer No: `3*10^13` = `19`. Surely we want to sleep for more than 19 milliseconds. The `^` operator is the binary xor. There is no power operator in Java. Only `Math.pow` which also returns a `double` and therefore requires a cast, increasing the total byte count, not decreasing it.

Comment: Does this count here without alle the main class and the try catch for the interruption exception?

Comment: @avalancha [Consensus is that lambdas are fine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4727/16236). You don't need to try/catch in lambdas since it relies on declaring interfaces that do all that for you. That's why I declared the `Sleeper` interface in my TIO. We're using several distinct rulings to get this far in golfing in Java.

Comment: awesome, thx for the link!

Comment: Can you use `7L<<42`? It's about 3e13, I think.

Comment: How come you don't need the semicolon at the end?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky [It's a lambda.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574386/about-lambda-semicolon)

Comment: Also works in scala (with `=>`  instead of `->`).

Answer (score 8):

## [Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), <s>41</s> 25 bytes

<sup><sup>-8 bytes thanks to AdmBorkBork

-6 bytes thanks to ceilingcat

-2 bytes thanks to inspiration from Neil</sup></sup>

```
ping 1 -n 31556952000>nul
```

Using [31,556,952](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9141871/4475014) seconds / year and a (default) 1 second delay between each ping, this will wait 1000 years before returning nothing.

Note that `ping 1` results in failure but it'll fail 31 billion times so that still works.

Comment: How about `1.1.1.1` to save two bytes? Sure, it's not a valid "test" address (sorry, Cloudflare), but hey, it's code-golf. ;-)

Comment: Actually, more than that, because you can therefore do `-n 31556952000000>nul` and skip the `-w`, since there's a one second delay between each ping.

Comment: Why not `1.0.0.1`, which abbreviates to `1.1`?

Answer (score 8):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-1 thanks to Eric Towers.

Full program. This works by observing that $$\sum_{n=1}^{8^6}n=3.44×10^{10}\approx3.16×10^{10}$$which is the number of seconds in a thousand years.

```apl
⎕dl¨⍳8*6
```

[Don't try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1JScQyse9W620DL7/x8A)

`8*6` \$8^6=262144\$

`⍳` **ɩ**ntegers until that

`⎕dl¨` **d**e**l**ay each of those many seconds

Comment: I don't know APL, but is ```⎕dl¨3e10``` good for 8 bytes?

Comment: @79037662 `¨` is "each" which wouldn't be needed in this case, but no, `3e10` is for some reason too big an argument for `⎕dl` which appears to have a limit of 2147483 seconds.

Comment: `8*6` = 262144, giving 1088.8... years.

Comment: @EricTowers Incorporated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 11 bytes

```
Pause[2^35]
```

2 to the 35th power is about 8.9% greater than 31,556,926,000.

Comment: I’m not at my computer right now to check, but can you save a byte with Pause@2^35 ?

Comment: Tried that—it pauses for 2 seconds and returns `Null^35` :D

Answer (score 7):

## T-SQL, 56 bytes

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=0a:WAITFOR TIME'9:0'SET @+=1IF @<4E5GOTO a
```

- The SQL [`WAITFOR`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/waitfor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) command is limited to 24 hours, so it has to go in a loop.
- `WAITFOR` has two options: `DELAY` that waits a certain length of time, or `TIME` which waits until a certain time of day. Turns out `WAITFOR TIME'9:0'` (which will pause until 9am the following day) is a couple of bytes shorter than `WAITFOR DELAY'24:0'`.
- Using a `GOTO` loop is shorter than a `WHILE` loop.
- I'm looping `4E5` times (400,000), which is within 10% of the 10-year (365,242 day) goal.
- If I start it today, this would complete in February, 3115

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 24 bytes

```r
sapply(1:25e4,Sys.sleep)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzixoCCnUsPQysg01UQnuLJYrzgnNbVA8/9/AA)

A solid starter, feels like there's optimisation to be had with a different function & number combo. This sleeps for 1s, then 2s, then 3s, then 4s... up to 250000s, at which point it's been running for about 990 years and outputs a list of 250k empty elements.

Comment: why not 3e10 like the other answers

Comment: @qwr `Sys.sleep(3e10)` doesn't work, and I couldn't figure out a shorter way to write some version of `for(i in 1:3e10)Sys.sleep(1)` that works. If there is one then more fool me!

Comment: @qwr it occurred that there's a less obvious reason for this being the shortest one I found: `25e4` is the same length as `3e10`, but `sapply` allows us to pass the counter into the function without parentheses making it valuable to find a number with sums along to roughly `3e10`. The `1:25e4` is doing double duty here.

Comment: why doesn't Sys.sleep(3e10) work?

Comment: I'm not 100% on the why of it, but the documentation says on Windows `Sys.sleep` uses `Sleep`. I'm not knowledgeable of the specifics there, but the outcome is that it sleeps for a few milliseconds rather than a thousand years. Might behave differently on Linux?

Answer (score 6):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 38 bytes

```lua
t=os.time;o=t()+2^35while t()<o do end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/xDa/WK8kMzfVOt@2RENT2yjO2LQ8IzMnVQHIs8lXSMlXSM1L@f8fAA)

Being ANSI C compliant, Lua does not implement any sleep functions, so we have to make one ourselves. Oh, and make sure to keep the dust off that One Thousand Year Computer, we're busy waiting.

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 38 bytes

```lua
t=os.time;o=t()+2^35repeat until o<t()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/xDa/WK8kMzfVOt@2RENT2yjO2LQotSA1sUShNK8kM0ch3wYo/P8/AA)

Same thing, different loop. Tried to see if I can save some bytes, but nope.

Comment: What the dingle bells, why does `35while` not throw the parser into conniptions? Today I learned something about Lua I didn't want to know.

Comment: @Caleb In upcoming Lua 5.4, this will no longer works. They have learnt this lesson. Also, tio.run really should provide different Lua versions due to significant changes (this one will cause a lot of 5.3 golf break if they'll just update).

Answer (score 6):

## [gbz80](https://rgbds.gbdev.io/docs/v0.5.2/gbz80.7) [machine code](https://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/gameboy/gameboy_opcodes.html) program, 40 (6 + 34) bytes

VBlank handler (put at 0x40)

```
CD 5A 01 F1 FB 76
```

Program after entrypoint (put at 0x150)

```
01 B7 02 21 FF FF 36 01 FB 76 2D 20 14 25 20 11
1D 20 0E 15 20 0B 0D 20 08 05 20 05 2F E0 21 E0
23 C9
```

Runs a timer that decrements every frame. At the Game Boy's frame rate, one thousand years is ~1,884,804,967,414 (0x1B6D7216BF6) frames (with a frame rate of 59.727500569606 fps and the assumption of 24 hours per day and 365.24 days per year). This program's timer runs for 0x1B6****FEFE frames. The stars are that the middle registers aren't initialized, and the bottom registers are used for an optimization, but the three most significant hex figures are correct and therefore the timer will be well within tolerance.

After the thousand years, the noise channel plays for a short while, and there will be a looping timer that will play the sound every ~149,339 years. Those are some good AAs.

Maybe it could be shorter if you want to cycle count instead of VBlank count.

Source:

```
section "VBlankInterrupt", ROM0[$40]
    call VBlankHandled
    pop af                  ; get rid of pushed return address
    ei                      ; enable interrupts
    db $76                  ; directly encoded halt, one byte saved over "halt"
                            ; ei and halt interact buggily, but it doesn't matter here because we discard the return address.

section "Header", ROM0[$100]
    jr AfterEntryPoint      ; thing for every Game Boy program, shouldn't count

    ds $150 - @, 0          ; Make room for the header

AfterEntryPoint:
    ld bc, $02B7            ; we have to set b one higher, because we decrement then check for zero. also did c because no reason not to and more accuracy
                            ; d and e will be set to their startup values.
    ld hl, $FFFF            ; double-use: part of timer and as a pointer
    ld [hl], $01            ; enable v-blank interrupt only
    ei
    db $76                  ; necessary halt to prevent stack underflow from return, again the return address is discarded so ei halt bug isn't a worry
VBlankHandled:
    dec l
    jr nz, .backToSleep
    dec h
    jr nz, .backToSleep
    dec e
    jr nz, .backToSleep
    dec d
    jr nz, .backToSleep
    dec c
    jr nz, .backToSleep
    dec b
    jr nz, .backToSleep
.madeItOut:
    cpl                     ; invert a, which is 01 from the pop
    ldh [$21], a
    ldh [$23], a            ; this and previous turn on and up the noise channel, which briefly plays because of time limit not being turned off
.backToSleep:
    ret
```

Comment: "Noise channel" and unpredictable waiting time are great additional details! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 59 bytes

```cs
b=>{for(var d=DateTime.Now.AddYears(999);d>DateTime.Now;);}
```

Can be tested by replacing `AddYears()` with `AddSeconds()`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcqxCgIxDADQ/b6i3NQiHq6ltnCgm7goiGNsImSwhTToIH57XU9wfi@3dW7c56xcy5aLJgOx32J636vYJ4jBuAOlMz9oOtbXNCNeCaRZ770LmJYYXPj0MFyElQ5cyI4nBVFCA2rG1bK6MIDduJ@8L/i/9i8)

Comment: Couldn't this be shortened by eliminating 'd' and making the 'for' a 'while'?

Comment: @bta you mean `while (DateTime.Now.AddYears(999) > DateTime.Now);` ? but that would result in an endless loop, as if I don't initially store `DateTime.Now` in a variable it will keep updating it`s value.

Comment: [54](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/Lb9IoyyxSCHF1iWxJDUkMzdVzy@/XM8xJSUyNbGoWMPS0lLTOsUOWdJa0/r/fwA) - you don't need to wrap the code in a function.

Answer (score 5):

### Mumps (M): 7 Bytes

```
H 9**11
```

Mumps likes single-letter commands & big numbers... H(ang) sleeps for ## of seconds; 9 to the 11th power gives 31381059609 seconds, which is almost 0.6% low for 1000 years; well within the margin of error.

Keeping with the 7 byte code length, I tested "power of 9" sleep times on 2 different Mumps implementations; the largest power of 9 on YottaDB/GT.M I can find without numeric overflow would be:

```
H 9**49
```

which gives a sleep time of just over 1,814 *decillion* millennia.  InterSystems' Cache doesn't overflow and can go to:

```
H 9**99
```

which gives 9.352x10<sup>83</sup> millennia. That's quite a nap in 7 bytes!

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
VT.dC"¼€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyxEL8VZ6dAeSeFDDf//AwA)

There are [exactly 31,557,600 seconds in the Julian astronomical year.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year), totalling 31,557,600,000 seconds in 1000 years. 2^32 is about a tenth of this, so we just wait for 3,155,760,000 seconds ten times.
Note that `€` is a blank codepoint in the TIO, not sure why it translates to this on SE

[Here](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/31np0B5J4UMNSv//AwA) you can see that `C"¼€` is equal to 3,155,760,000

[And here](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/P8xIL8VZiVvp/38A) is an example that waits for only 22 seconds using a similar method

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
.dC"XúÃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy/FWYk94vCuw83//wMA)

Alternatively, this one just uses `C"XúÃ` for 31,557,600,000. I thought it was more in line with the spirit of the challenge to have a 2^32 limit, though

---

The average length of a sidereal year, however, is 365.256363004 days or around 31,558,149.763 seconds, giving us a total of ~31,558,149,764 seconds in 1000 years. In this case, the more accurate solution would be

[This:](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyxEL8VZ6dAeycOrHP7/BwA) `VT.dC"¼ê@`

[This:](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy/FWYk9klntUPP//wA)`.dC"Y&ƒ`(1 byte longer than Julian solution)

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 18 bytes

```perl
sleep 1e9for 1..30
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784JzW1QMEw1TItv0jBUE/P2OD/fwA)

10 bytes (doesn't work)

```perl
sleep 3e10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784JzW1QME41dDg/38A)

Comment: [Polyglot with Perl 6/Raku](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784JzW1QME41dDg/38A)

Comment: actually it doesn't work : `sleep() with negative argument`

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://www.php.net/), 30 bytes

The time() function can be used instead of microtime(1), as when plused with 3e10, PHP converts the value into a float, even when the original value is an int and thereby save some more bytes.

```
time_sleep_until(time()+3e10);
```

[See how php converts values](https://paiza.io/projects/e/0rG2h78IIabH87PlTe22ng)

As stated by "manassehkatz-Reinstate Monica" a flag can be set to make it run without the tags in PHP, so a more clean version is here made. (36 bytes)

```
time_sleep_until(microtime(1)+3e10);
```

Google tells me that 1000 years = 3.1556926 × 10<sup>10</sup> seconds (31,556,926,000)
The method cloud even be made recoverable in the event of power failures. (not done in this example)

```
<?php time_sleep_until(microtime(true)+31556926000)); ?>
```

The shorter but more imprecise version (45 bytes with the php tags)

```
<?php time_sleep_until(microtime(1)+3e10); ?>
```

With a correction from "Kaddath" this option below is dropped as the documentation state that it is a int not a float used in sleep()
<strike>It can be done like so:</strike>

```
<?php sleep(31556926000); ?>
```

[Try it online!](https://paiza.io/projects/e/fFEGQvTU8U95mEyt-bVmeQ)

Comment: I love how you've added a "Try it online!" link :')

Comment: I think it would work with `1+"3e10"` which saves 3 bytes ;) (automatic conversion to `float` and actually `31556926000` is already a float, not an int)

Comment: Well after having tested, my previous comment's suggestion doesn't work, but that means yours will not either: `sleep` converts argument to an `int`, so the value used will be `1492154928` when you use `31556926000`, which is "only" 47.3 years (hard to verify, I know, must trust the documentation on this).. Sorry!

Comment: However, the second code with `time_sleep_until` will work, because it uses a float, and there you actually can use `microtime(true)+"3e10"`.. EDIT: even better: `microtime(1)+"3e10"`

Comment: I updated my response based on your feedback Kaddath, but we do not need "" around 3e10, so we can save 2 bytes more :)

Comment: Congrats Mikki! Thanks for representing PHPers! 
PS: do you really need the closing tag `?>`? ;D

Comment: You can remove ?> And I know there is a flag to make it run without <?php that  is routinely used in Code Golf.

Comment: Victor F and manassehkatz-Reinstate Monica you are right, i think i will switch my score and make a note :)
As you might have spotted im new to Code Golf, so thanks for the tips :)

Comment: Just as a note, here’s the related meta post, explaining why and in which cases the opening tag can be discarded: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7098/41859

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (Node.js), <s>70</s>, <s>67</s>, 34 bytes

-3 thanks to Joost K, see their [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/197019/87378) for why I used `8e6`
-33 thanks to Benjamin Gruenbaum for pointing out callbacks are better, using the concept of his answer

I've found 2 ways of solving this problem.
The first defines `a` globally:

```js
(f=_=>a&&setTimeout(f,--a))(a=8e6)
```

the other method passes `a` through each time, using `setTimeout`'s further args:

```js
(f=a=>a&&setTimeout(f,--a,a))(8e6)
```

These solutions remain the same length when using IIFEs or just calling the function manually.

Comment: You can remove the space to save another byte :)

Comment: you can cut down 3 bytes by changing the loop like t=77e5;--t; and using t as the time to wait.`setTimeout(r,t)` See my C# answer where I use this in C#

Comment: @JoostK Clever, I'll add that in now, thanks :)

Comment: Same concept but with callbacks instead of promises :] 
`(function f(a){setTimeout(f,--a)})(8e6);` at 40 characters

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Wouldn't this carry on forever? and isn't a undefined?

Comment: @Kobe no - We are defining and immediately executing a function and passing 8e6 as a parameter.

Comment: I mean it will recurse forever, since there is not condition stopping the `setTimeout` from calling `f` again. And `a` will not be passed through on any of the iterations, you'd have to use `_=>f(a)` right? @BenjaminGruenbaum

Comment: Oh yeah you're right it's missing the `a&&` part

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <strike>38</strike> 37 bytes

this waits 1 + 2 + 3.. +77e5-1 + 77e5ms.

I got this 77e5 magic number using the formula `(x+1)/2*x=3e13` where x results in approximately `7.745.967` which I shortened to 77e5.

To check if it still falls in the allowed range I did `1000*365.25*24*3600*1000/((77e5+1)/2*77e5)` which is `1.064` aka 6.45% of target

update : 8e6 results in `0.98` more precise and less bytes.

```cs
for(var i=0;i++<8e6;)Thread.Sleep(i);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/F9anJmXrhBcWVySmqsXklGUmpgCFLDm4uIKL8osSfXJzEvVUAouSSwqSU1RSCxRUNJ2SSxJDcnMTdXzyy/XtP6fll@kUZZYpJBpa2Cdqa1tY5FqZq0JMUgvOCc1tUAjE6gKyTDXvBQcRgEA)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
₆9e.W
```

Sleeps for about 1082 years.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVObZape@P//AA)

```
₆         # push 36
 9        # push 9
  e       # nPr (number of 9-element permutations of a 36-element list)
   .W     # wait that many milliseconds
```

Answer (score 4):

## TI-BASIC, 17 bytes

```
For(I,0,2^32:rand(564:End
```

TI-BASIC doesn't have any wait commands/functions, so I just used one of the slowest functions available:  generating random lists!

Generating a random list of 564 elements takes \$\approx7.95\$ seconds to make and the loop goes through \$2^{32}\$ iterations, so that results in \$7.95*2^{32}=34144990003.2\$ seconds or \$1082.01255\$ years.

Answer (score 4):

## [Matlab](https://au.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html), 12 bytes

```matlab
pause(3e+10)
```

This will sleep for 951 years which is within 10% of 1000 years. Note that Matlab can sleep for a floating number of seconds.

This is my first ever answer on CodeGolf :)

Answer (score 4):

## x86-64 function, 10 bytes

```
6A 16 59 48 C1 E1 1F E0 FE C3
```

In assembly:

```
sleep_for_a_thousand_years:
    push 0x17
    pop rcx
    shl rcx,52
    loopnz $
    ret
```

This is a function

The `loopnz` opcode decrements the `rcx` register and jumps if the zero flag is not set and `rcx!=0` after it is decremented. `$` denotes the address of the `loopnz` address itself, so this just loops back to the same instruction over and over until `rcx` is zero.

`loopnz` is infamously slow, and the code before sets `rcx` to 103,582,791,429,521,408. So this will loop 103,582,791,429,521,408 times, which should take 1012 years, based on some benchmarks I did on TIO. (The number may need to be tweaked a bit if you have some overclocked monstrosity though.)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run) ... Actually, maybe skip that just this once.

Answer (score 3):

## [Applescript](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10), 10

```
delay 3e10
```

Sleeps for 3 * 10<sup>10</sup> seconds.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
35oF.Z
```

~8.879% too large

Also take a look at [this excellent alternative 6-byter by *@anatolyg*](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196978/52210).

**Previous 7-byters:**

```python
žqþ¨¨.W     # ~0.449% too small
žG14∍.W     # ~3.837% too large
13°3*.W     # ~4.936% too small
```

For 100%<sup><sup>*†*</sup></sup> precision (*†*: assuming a year is 365.25 days), use `•Tε‚šä¦•.W` (**10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**) instead.

**Explanations:**

```python
35          # Push 35
  o         # Pop and push 2 to the power 35: 34359738368
   F        # Loop that many times:
    .Z      #  And sleep for 1 second every iteration

žq          # Push PI with 15 decimal digits by default: 3.141592653589793
  þ         # Remove the dot by only leaving the digits: 3141592653589793
   ¨¨       # Remove the last two digits: 31415926535897
     .W     # Sleep that many ms

žG          # Push builtin integer 32768
  14∍       # Extend it to size 14: 32768327683276
     .W     # Sleep that many ms

13°         # Push 10 to the power 13: 10000000000000
   3*       # Multiply it by 3: 30000000000000
     .W     # Sleep that many ms

•Tε‚šä¦•    # Push compressed integer 31557600000000
        .W  # Sleep that many ms
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `•Tε‚šä¦•` is `31557600000000`.

05AB1E is built in [Elixir](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html), and [its sleep builtin](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Process.html#sleep/) can even hold `:infinity` apparently, so I can assume the `.W` has no maximum.

Comment: 5 bytes: `₆9e.W` (waits ~8% too long).

Comment: @Grimmy Nice, I knew 5 bytes should be possible somehow with some of the 1-byte constants and 1-byte builtins! I was playing around with palindromize, factorize, euler_constant, etc. but forgot about `e`. Feel free to post it as your own answer in this case, since there are already two 05AB1E answers and my answer is already a bit too full (don't really want to remove the 7 byters). I'll upvote you when you do.

Answer (score 3):

## SmileBASIC, 19 bytes

```
@L
WAIT 12e7GOSUB@L
```

Waits 120 000 000 frames (around 21.2 days), and loops until the GOSUB stack overflows (after 16383 iterations)
This lasts 1038.32 years

Comment: Implicit outer loop - this is a great idea!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (browser), 19 bytes

```javascript
setTimeout("a",3e13)
```

This will throw and error in about a 1000 years.

Answer (score 2):

## SAS, 38 bytes

```
data;do i=1to 3e10;a=sleep(1);end;run;
```

This loop seems to be the shortest option as both `sleep` and `wakeup` are capped at 46 days - slightly less than 2<sup>22</sup> seconds. I wonder what the rationale for that was?

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 34 bytes

uses the 3e13 like most answers but in a for loop.
The `1` at the end is to make it a valid for loop.

```javascript
d=Date.now;for(i=d();i>d()-3e13;)1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/xdYlsSRVLy@/3Dotv0gj0zZFQ9M60w5I6hqnGhpbaxr@/w8A)

Don't actually try it...

Answer (score 2):

## [Roblox](https://www.roblox.com/create), 11 bytes

```lua
wait(3e+10)
```

Waits 30,000,000,000 seconds, which is roughly equal to 950 years.

Answer (score 2):

## [MSX-BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSX_BASIC), 47 characters

```
1FORK=1TO31557600000:TIME=0
2IFTIME<50GOTO2
3NEXT
```

`TIME` is a MSX-BASIC system variable holding a 50Hz counter that can be initialized to any value at will. There are 31557600000 seconds in 1000 years (assuming one leap year every 4 years) so there you go.

Answer (score 2):

### Zsh/Bash/Sh, <strike>23</strike>,<strike>19</strike>,<strike>14</strike>,10 bytes

```
sleep 8e6h
```

*-4 bytes thanks to [@Grimmy](/users/6484/grimmy)*

### Explanation

[GNU coreutils sleep](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sleep-invocation.html) command can take a suffix of either `s` (*seconds*), `m` (*minutes*), `h` (*hours*), or `d` (*days*). It also accepts IEEE-754 numbers, which allows us to use the shorter form of `8e6` to specify 8M hours.

8 million hours is equivalent to roughly 912½ years.

Comment: `sleep 3e10`, `sleep 8e6h`, `sleep 5e8m` are all 10 bytes and within the 10% tolerance.

Comment: @Grimmy Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## RPL, 8 bytes

```
3E10WAIT
```

shall wait 3e10 seconds on, say, your hp48sx. Good the OP excluded hardware issues, so we can ignore the reboot at the end of Dec. 31st, 2088 (the date is reinitialized to Jan. 1st, 1989.)

For RPL/2, add one byte as a space is needed before `WAIT`.

I am surprised such commands are accepted anyhow…

Btw a challenge about 2763 years would allow us to use the factorial as in `14!WAIT`.

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
{tï╜Ä_⌐_¬Wó+<}▲
```

Just like [my top 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196965/52210), it's ~8.879% too large.

[Try it online with debugging argument `-d` to see what's going on.](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9tYXRoZ29sZv//e3TDr@KVnMOEX@KMkF/CrFfDsys8feKWsv///y1k)

**Explanation:**

There were a few difficulties to tackle here:

1. Apparently there is no way in MathGolf to access a value outside of the scope of a while-loop. I therefore had to push the initial timestamp inside the loop, and by using some duplicates and stack-rotates access it to check against the current timestamp.
2. After that I initially had `{t_⌐_¬Wó+<}▲` (12 bytes) to overcome the issue mentioned at point 1. Unfortunately there are some bugs in MathGolf, so this required a leading `1`, otherwise the do-while didn't work: `1{t_⌐_¬Wó+<}▲`.
3. MathGold is built in Python, and [since Python's List size is limited to 536,870,912 items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/855455/1682559), I therefore had to remove unused garbage from the stack instead of letting it grow by one additional item every iteration. (Since it executes roughly 5-10 iterations per ms on TIO, the stack size grows way too fast to last even close to 1000 years.) I did this by adding an if-statement in front of that initial duplicate, so I only duplicate it in the very first iteration. For some reason I could now also remove that `1` which was used as a bug-workaround..

Putting it all together gave me the 15-byter you see here, with the following code explanation:

```python
{            }▲  # Do-while true with pop:
 t               #  Push the current timestamp
  ï              #  Push the current 0-based loop-index
   ╜             #  If it's falsey (so it's the first iteration):
    Ä            #   Execute the following single command:
     _           #    Duplicate this initial timestamp
      ⌐          #  Rotate the stack, so the bottom item is at the top
       _         #  Duplicate it
        ¬        #  And rotate the stack back, so its both at the top and bottom now
         Wó      #  Push 35, and then pop and push 2**35: 34359738368
           +     #  Add it to the timestamp of the first iteration
            <    #  And check whether it's still lower than the current timestamp
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

*-1 byte because I forgot that e[numeric literal] existed.*

```
es3e13+{_es>}g
```

[Please don't try it online, it won't work!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P7XYONXQWLs6PrXYrjb9/38A)

This waits in a while loop until the current Unix timestamp is equal to the timestamp at the beginning of execution plus 3*10^13 milliseconds (or ~951.3 years).

Answer (score 2):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 55 bytes

```rust
||std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::new(2<<34,0))
```

[Try it online! (or not, it will take ~1089 years to do anything interesting)](https://tio.run/##TYzBCoMwEETvfkXqaQNSStvTqvTSSz8j4JYG4kaSlQjqt6eRXnqZgXmPCXOU/GY1GsugV0eiFtWrvG1RBkT5BDKloyOa4DfZkRCfczBiPSMyJbh23e3eXLTObXVcsE/l5E9/cRTDUmyfQLfVcsQULIvjE9QrPva6KexMzkyRBtCF7/kL)

Rust's `thread::sleep` takes a `Duration` as an input, and those conveniently store the count of seconds as a u64.

Answer (score 2):

## VBA, 27 bytes

This program adds an approximation of 1000 years, in days, to the current time, and instructs the program to wait until that time is encountered.

```vb
Application.Wait 365242+Now
```

For for a more accurate result, the below may be used at a cost of 41 bytes.

```vb
Application.Wait DateAdd("yyyy",1000,Now)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>46</strike> 48 bytes

```python
import time
for _ in range(7889):time.sleep(4e6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVKy2/SCFeITNPoSgxLz1Vw9zCwlLTCiSjV5yTmlqgYZJqpvn/PwA)

Based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196932/106829) answer. Used for loop to circumvent the overflow in `time.sleep()`. <strike>`3e10` shows overflow but `3e9` doesn't.</strike> No Overflow errors are show on the online interpreters(TIO and ATO) but on attempting on personal computer it does show error. The suggestion by @anatolyg has been implemented, which is working on both interpreters.

### Previous erroneous answer

```python
import time
for _ in range(10):time.sleep(3e9)
```

Comment: On my Windows machine, `sleep(3e9)` overflows. Maximal number of seconds for which `sleep` succeeds is 4294967 (`2**32/1000`). Here, the following code would work: `for _ in range(7889):time.sleep(4e6)`. On which platform does `sleep(3e9)`  succeed?

Comment: @anatolyg `sleep(3e9)` works for me on TIO and ATO(online code execution). I have now checked my code on my computer and it does show Overflow error for `3e9`. Perhaps the online interpreters are using some kind of optimization. Either way, I will change my answer to reflect your point.

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
    6!:3\i.2^18
```

### Explanation:

- `6!:3`:  'delay' function
- `\`: Loop over the entire following value
- `i.2^18`: A list of values from 0 to (2^18)-1

Thanks to @CriminallyVulgar for the 2^18 idea!
[Try it online... or maybe don't](https://tio.run/##y/r/30zRyjgmU88oztDi/38A)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 42 bytes

```
integer(kind=8)i;i=56**6
call sleep(i)
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v/PzCtJTU8t0sjOzEuxtdDMtM60NTXT0jLjSk7MyVEozklNLdDI1ORKzUv5/x8A)

Gnu Fortran's `sleep` routine only works with an integer number of seconds. Problem is, the default integer type in GFortran only goes up to `2147483647` which only gets us to less than 100 years, and (according to the `units` utility) we need approx `3.1556926e+10` seconds to get us to 1000 years. But we can tweak `i` to a larger type, using `kind=8`, which works fine with `sleep`.

Setting `i=56**6` gets us to `30840979456` seconds, which is more interesting (and closer to 1000 years) than `i=3e10`. I found this number by messing around with cube roots and higher with gnu `bc -l`. Example: `e(l(3e10)/3)` in `bc` gets the cube root, `e(l(3e10)/6)` gets the 6th root!

I suppose I could have just [looped the program a few times](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v9PyVfItDXUMTS0Tk7MyVEozklNLdDIKE1P1cjU1LROzUtJyecCkv//AwA) instead of faffing about with integer types but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 2):

## Minecraft Command, 45 bytes

```
/summon wind_charge ~5 ~ ~ {Motion:[-7e-12d]}
```

Summons a wind charge 5 blocks away from the player, with a motion towards the player of 7×10⁻¹² blocks per gametick. The wind charge moves slowly towards the player until it's less than 0.6 blocks away, where it touches the player's hitbox and explodes.

This takes (5 - 0.6) / 7e-12 = 628571428571 gameticks or 31428571429 seconds, which is 0.4% less than 1000 years (assuming each year is 365.2425 days long).

This is what it looks like sped up by a factor of 10¹⁰.

[image: gif of wind charge sped up]

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 9 bytes

```
wait 3e10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0pN@R@UmhId@788MbNEwTjV0OD/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](https://tcl.tk/), 23 bytes

```
after 30000000000000000
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f8/Ma0ktUjB2AAN/P8PAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [at](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(command)), 19 bytes

```
at now + 1000 years
```

Comment: @JoKing I think it's linux command [at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at)

Comment: You don't need the plural on "years" for the date parsing here, nor the spaces actually: `at now+1000year` is 15 bytes and does the same work.

Comment: @ceving @Caleb I'm not familiar with this language, but why not use ```at now+999year```? An error of less than ±10% is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## **[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), all platforms, 91 bytes**

```
from datetime import *;z=datetime.now()+timedelta(days=365242)
while z>datetime.now(): pass
```

The rules say simple termination is fine, which happens after the while loop is done. I couldn't put it all on one line, because the `while` loop has to start on its own line for the interpreter to recognize it. I also didn't want to use `sleep` since the challenge specifically calls that out as the problem.

Comment: The spaces before `*` and after `:` are not necessary. Instead of `pass` you can use a simple value, the shortest would be a single digit number.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 10 bytes

```factor
3e16 sleep
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7GqlUJJRlJqYUvzfONXQTKE4JzW14P9/AA)

Factor's `sleep` word is a generic word that can take either a real number denoting nanoseconds or a duration. 3e16 nanoseconds is within 5% error of 1000 years if my calculations are correct.

More straightforward at the cost of some bytes:

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 15 bytes

```factor
1e3 years sleep
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnJiTmpeSWKRQklGUmphSrGD93zDVWKEyNbGoWKE4JzW14P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ê¼@µ~¼
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=88ac40e67eac&i=)

### Approach

17¹⁰ times: wait for one animation frame at 60fps.

[Here's](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=975f017f42) a test for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

## Commodore BASIC (Commodore C64/128, C16/+4, VIC-20, CBM/PET), 92 Tokenised BASIC bytes

A thousand years in the Gregorian Calendar at least 365,240 days, plus two or three days depending on the 400 year rule, whereby each start of a new century is a leap year but only once every 400 years, with the year 2000 being a leap year, but 1900 and 2100 are not leap years. As the next leap year at the start of a century will be 2400 I will assume that you want to sleep for 365,242 days. How do we do this with Commodore BASIC?

A day according to a Commodore BASIC interpreter is 5,184,001 jiffies (or 1/60 of a second), which is actually one 60th too many, so over 365,242 days, we are out by the same number of jiffies, which is about 101 minutes, so we will be sleeping for about 1000 years + 101 minutes based on our assumptions above. You can see an explanation of the Commodore TI and TI$ functions on the 8-BIT Show and Tell YouTube channel [here](https://youtu.be/VkabHdR15xs?feature=shared).

Firstly, we need to take a copy of the current system time, which one can set in `HHMMSS` in a 24 hour format like `TI$="123000"` - we then need a busy loop to wait a second so that the copy of the current time and the system timer are not the same. I am also setting the number of days to wait in the `W` variable, which is 365241 as our counter `D` starts at zero.

```
0 C$=TI$: W=365241: D=0: FOR I=0 TO 937: NEXT I
```

Now, we need to wait until TI$ is equal to our copy stored in C$, each time it is we know that it has been 24 hours and 1/60th of a second. When this is true, we can jump to a sub routine that will add 1 to the number of days, and return. Note that using `STEP 0` in our `FOR/NEXT` loop creates an endless loop with our break condition being in the subroutine on line 2.

```
1 FOR I=0 TO 1 STEP 0: ON -(TI$=C$) GOSUB 2: NEXT I
```

When we jump to the subroutine at line 2, TI$ and C$ may still contain the same values, so we need a busy loop until TI$ is one second ahead again of C$. Then we can add 1 to our day counter, and if the counter has fewer days than our `W` variable set above, we will return from our sub-routine which will wait again until another 24 hours and 1 jiffy has passed.

```
2 ON -(TI$=C$) GOTO 2: D=D+1: IF D<W THEN RETURN
```

The full crunched listing (with removed whitespaces) would look like this:

```
0C$=TI$:W=365241:D=.:FORI=.TO1E3:NEXT
1FORI=.TO1STEP.:ON-(TI$=C$)GOSUB2:NEXT
2ON-(TI$=C$)GOTO2:D=D+1:IFD<WTHENRETURN
```

[image: Commodore C64 Sleep for 1000 years]

Answer (score 1):

## [YASEPL](https://github.com/madeforlosers/YASEPL-esolang), 31 bytes

```
=aŔ9+31556952000000`1=bŔ9}2,a
```

terminates when finished.

sets a date to `a`, adds 1000 years in milliseconds, then goes into a while loop that checks if the current date is less than `a`. aka:

```javascript
let a = new Date() + 31556952000000;

do {
  let b = new Date();
} while(b < a);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 7 bytes

```
&sl3e10
```

### Explanation

```
&sl3e10
   3e10 # Push 30000000000 to the stack
&sl     # Sleep for that many seconds
```

On Uiua's online pad, `&sl` hangs the page for how many seconds specified. [Here's a sample that hangs for 10 seconds.](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=0_10_0-dev_1__JnNsMTAK)

Unfortunately, 3e10 seconds is only around 951 years, so everyone'll have to wait 49 more. [Thankfully it's only 95.07% of a millennium in seconds.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3e10+is+what+percent+of+31556952000)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/editor/) ([scratchblocks3](http://scratchblocks.github.io/v3/) syntax), 30 bytes

It's the obvious solution but it's surprisingly short for a Scratch program. Sleeps for exactly 951.3 years + a few milliseconds.

```
when gf clicked
wait(3e10)secs
```

Comment: I don't think it'd be a few milliseconds, since you're giving it an integer amount of seconds?

Comment: @noodleman Scratch adds a small artificial delay after each block

Comment: Ah, forgot about the delay.

Answer (score 0):

### Pascal, 284 B

This complete Pascal `program` requires a processor supporting features defined by ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal”, in particular the `timeStamp` built‑in data type and `getTimeStamp` routine.
The program simply performs a [busy wait](https://en.WikiPedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).

```pascal
program p;var r,n:timeStamp;begin getTimeStamp(r);with r do begin
year:=year+1000;day:=day-ord(month=2)*ord(not(0 in[year mod 4]-[year mod 100]+[year mod 400]));repeat
getTimeStamp(n)
until[1=1]=[n.year=year,n.month=month,n.day=day,n.hour=hour,n.minute=minute,n.second=second]end end.
```

The `program` terminates if exactly 1 kiloyears have passed (second granularity), else it is non‑terminating (for instance if the operating system’s scheduler put the `program` in a *waiting state* during the crucial second).

```pascal
program millenniumSleep;
    var
        reference, now: timeStamp;
    begin
        getTimeStamp(reference);
        { We presume `reference.dateValid` and `reference.timeValid` are `true`.
          The processor does feature an operational real­‑time clock. }
        
        with reference do
        begin
            { Add a millennium to `timeStamp`. }
            year ≔ year + 1000;
            { Accommodate for leap day. }
            day  ≔ day − ord(month = 2) *
                ord(not (0 in [year mod 4] − [year mod 100] + [year mod 400]));
            
            { We presume evaluation of the loop takes at most one second. }
            repeat
            begin
                getTimeStamp(now);
            end
            { The embracing `with reference do` language construct
              allows us to abbreviate `reference.year` to `year` and so forth. }
            until [true] = [now.year = year, now.month = month, now.day = day,
                now.hour = hour, now.minute = minute, now.second = second]
        end
    end.
```

The [leap year test](/a/254444/94076) has been adopted from a different challenge.
The `program` needs to be started before the year `maxInt − 1000`.
The value of the built‑in constant `maxInt` is implementation‑defined.

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 25 bytes

```
{Thread.sleep(7L shl 42)}
```

111 followed by 41 zeros (binary) is ~97.56% of 31556952000000 (decimal)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp6GpYKvwvzokoyg1MUWvOCc1tUDD3EehOCNHwcRIs/a/XmZeWX52qobmfwA)